# PHP specifying timeout duration for DOMDocument?

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a code that will scrap some data from a website using PHP DomDocument. However, I would like to specify the timeout duration. Is there any way to do so?

The code that I have is something like this:

```
<?php 
$grep = new DoMDocument(); 
@$grep->loadHTMLFile("http://www.example.com"); 
$finder = new DomXPath($grep); 
$class = "Cat"; 
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$class')]"); 

foreach ($nodes as $node) 
{ 

//coding    
}   
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use `fil_get_contents()` and set there the timeout duration, then feeding the return values into the DOMDocument class:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array('timeout' => 60), // 60 seconds
));
$html_page = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com', false, $context);

$grep = new DoMDocument(); 
@$grep->loadHTML($html_page); 
$finder = new DomXPath($grep); 
$class = "Cat"; 
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$class')]");
```

Answer (score 0):

The function [`libxml_set_streams_context()`](https://www.php.net/libxml_set_streams_context) can be used to *"set the streams context for the next libxml document load or write"*.

```
$opts = [
    'http' => [
        'timeout' => 10, // 10 seconds
    ]
];

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
libxml_set_streams_context($context);

$grep = new DoMDocument(); 
$grep->loadHTMLFile("https://www.example.com");
```

See also other [available HTTP context options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php).